# Is it possible to configure wdio to make use of different tsconfig files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webdriver-io

I'm trying to get wdio setup to run our React TypeScript app. The problem is that it only works if I modify the `tsconfig.json` file itself to make use of the required `types`, change `module` to `commonjs` and set `isolatedModules` to `false`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["node", "@wdio/sync", "@wdio/jasmine-framework"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is to be-able to break this out into separate `tsconfig.json` files and make use of each as and when needed. For example, when running `wdio` for our integration tests I only want it to make use of the `tsconfig.test.json` file, something like the following:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [ "./*" ],
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node", "@wdio/sync", "@wdio/jasmine-framework"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I've tried setting the `jasmineNodeOpts` in `wdio.conf.js` itself to retrieve the `tsconfig.test.json` but it didn't work. Is there a way to tell `wdio`, either via a flag or whatever, to use a specific `tsconfig` file?

**EDIT**

Added `wdio.conf.js` jasmine object:

```
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // TypeScript setup
        requires: ['ts-node/register'],
        // helpers: ["helper.js"],
        // Jasmine default timeout
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
        //
        // The Jasmine framework allows interception of each assertion in order to log the state of the application
        // or website depending on the result. For example, it is pretty handy to take a screenshot every time
        // an assertion fails.
        expectationResultHandler: function(passed, assertion) {
            // do something
        }
    },
```

**EDIT 2**

Following on from Jon's advice I installed `cross-env` and changed my script to this:

```
"int": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.test.json wdio wdio.conf.js",
```

But this now throws up another error, specifically in my dummy test:

```
import { openApp } from "./utils";

describe("Example.ts", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    openApp(browser, 'localhost');
  });
  it("should go to home page", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And the error:

```
import { openApp } from "./utils";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

If I change the `module` in the `tsconfig.test.json` to `commonjs` it moves past this error and starts to complain about the types:

```
 Error:  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
integration-tests/utils/index.ts(1,15): error TS7006: Parameter 'browser' implicitly has an 'any' type.
integration-tests/utils/index.ts(3,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'host'.
integration-tests/utils/index.ts(6,18): error TS7006: Parameter 'browser' implicitly has an 'any' type.
integration-tests/utils/index.ts(6,27): error TS7006: Parameter 'path' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

The curious thing here is that by changing the module you'd think then that it's picking up the test config but why isn't it loading the required types for the test?

Comment: That's using `ts-node` right? You should be able to set `TS_NODE_PROJECT` to tell it where the config file you want to use is.

Comment: And how would you use it? In the jasmineNodeOpts can you pass it? I'm making use of the requires object. See my edit.

Comment: It's an environment variable, you can set it using e.g. [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) in your package file scripts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe See my second edit

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, for me the problem was the way I was importing the `ts-node` library to my file.

When I changed **from**

```js
require('ts-node/register');
```

**to**

```js
require('ts-node');
```

The tests were able to run through without the TS compile issue.